# ¿como organizar el orden de impresion en un ciclo while?

Tags: c++, while

Necesito ayuda quiero que mi programa imprima así

Ticket 1's guess is 6

Ticket 2's guess is 3

Ticket 3's guess is 4

Ticket 4's guess is 5

Ticket 5's guess is 5

Ticket 6's guess is 5

Ticket 7's guess is 4

Ticket 8's guess is 5

Ticket 9's guess is 6

Ticket 10's guess is 5

The winning number is 5

Ticket 4 is a winner

Ticket 5 is a winner

Ticket 6 is a winner

Ticket 8 is a winner

Ticket 10 is a winner

y mi programa solo me imprime un ganador cuando hay mas

este es mi codigo

```
#include<iostream>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<time.h>
using namespace std;

int main(){
    srand(time(NULL));
    const int TICKET_COST=2;
    int n_tickets=0,confirmacion,ganancias,perdidas;
    double costo;
    char compu;

    cout<<"¿cuantos tickets va a comprar?\n";
    cin>>n_tickets;
    costo=n_tickets*TICKET_COST;
    cout<<"ingrese "<<costo<<" para confirmar: ";
    cin>>confirmacion;

    while(confirmacion != costo){
        cout<<"Re ingrese la confirmacion: ";
        cin>>confirmacion;
    }

    cout<<"Gracias le descontaremos $"<<costo<<" de su tarjeta"<<endl;

    int winner= 1+rand()%(11-1);
    int guess=0;
    int winCTR=0;
    string out="";

    cout<<"Si quiere que el computador genere los numeros ingrese Y en caso contrario ingrese N"<<endl;
    cin>>compu;
    if(compu=='Y' || compu=='y'){
        int i=1;
        while(i<=n_tickets){
            guess=1+rand()%(11-1);



            cout<<"ticket "<<i<<" guess es: "<<guess<<endl;


            if(guess== winner){
                winCTR++;
                out= "ticket "+to_string(i)+" ganador";
                //cout<<"ticket "<<i<<" es ganador"<<endl;
            }
            i++;


        }
        cout<<"el numero ganador es: "<<winner<<endl;
        cout<<"***"<<out<<endl;
        ganancias= winCTR*TICKET_COST*10;
        perdidas=(n_tickets-winCTR)*TICKET_COST;
        cout<<"su balance es $"<<(ganancias-confirmacion)<<endl;        

    }else if(compu=='N' || compu=='n'){

    }else{
        cout<<"Ingreso un valor invalido, cerrando el programa"<<endl;
        cout<<"se le rembolsara $"<<costo<<" a su tarjeta"<<endl;
        return 0;
    }


    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Y cual es el problema que te da el codigo?

Comment: solo me sale un valor cuando quiero imprimir los ganadores

Comment: El codigo que nos estas dando esta incompleto de paso, ya que no incluyes la definicion de la funcion to_string. Asi que ni siquiera lo puedo probar

Comment: to_string es una funcion de la libreria iostream

Comment: iostream significa input, output stream. No tiene sentido que esa funcion este declarada ahi. Ademas de que  iostream no dice contener esa funcion: [cplusplus](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/), [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/iostream). Al pegarlo en mi ordenador me tira error. Faltan cosas

Comment: @Pablochaches Está definida en la librería estándar de strings.

Comment: @FranAcuna Gracias

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cambia:

```
out= "ticket "+to_string(i)+" ganador";
```

Por:

```
out+= "ticket "+to_string(i)+" ganador\n";
```

Estas reasignando tu string `out`, en vez de acumular los diferentes resultados.

Comment: Muchas Gracias me funciono perfecto